# ada gtk warning (build fail)

Tags: build, gtk, warnings, ada

I'm trying to compile a simple GTk app, but when I compile, build fail due to warning in GTK source…

Compile log:

```
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
gdk-display.ads:361:80: (style) this line is too long
gdk-event.ads:290:80: (style) this line is too long
…
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Anybody have solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Choose not to treat warnings as errors.
2. Fix the issues the compiler complains about.

You can adjust compiler flags on a per-file basis in project files, so you don't have to drop your zero-warnings policy for the rest of the project, just because you do it for selected files in GtkAda.

Comment: It appear that the problem occur when I add `-gnatg` flag.